# Разделить фоновое изображение с 3D эффектом толщины

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3

Я хочу разделить фоновое изображение. Например - такой оригинальный образ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И хочу получить такой эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
<style>
    div{

    -webkit-transform: skewY(175deg); 
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 10px;
    background-image: url(Chrysanthemum.jpg);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-origin: content-box;
    }
</style>
<div></div>
```

Но я не могу найти любой способ, как разделить этот `background` с эффектом 3D толщины,  с помощью `CSS` или `jQuery`.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Split background image with 3D thickness effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39873279/7394871) от участника  [@ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3148644/ankit).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873279/split-background-image-with-3d-thickness-effect/39876163#39876163

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот этот 3D-подход, чтобы нарезать изображение на 3 части и сделать эффект толщины.

Это является масштабируемой техникой и зависит от:

- 3D-преобразования для вращения изображения и эффекта толщины
- техникой отступов - "padding technique" для сохранения пропорции
  элементов
- псевдо элементы, чтобы сделать толщину у каждой части изображения
- background image and background-position

[Демо](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/QKapxJ): 3d вращение и толщина изображения.

[image: 3d вращение и толщина изображения]

```css
body{perspective:1000px;}
.imgWrap{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  margin:5% auto;
  padding-bottom:39%;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.imgWrap > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:30.3%;height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/FhZxJJp.jpg');
  background-size:auto 100%;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  outline: 1px solid transparent; /* prevent jagged edges in firefox */
}
.imgWrap .left  { left: 0;     background-position:   3% 0; }
.imgWrap .center{ left:34.83%; background-position: -97% 0; }
.imgWrap .right { left:69.66%; background-position:-197% 0; }
.imgWrap > div:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:100%;
  width:10%; height:100%;
  background:inherit;
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
}
.imgWrap .left:before  { background-position:     0%   0; }
.imgWrap .center:before{ background-position: -1001.3% 0; }
.imgWrap .right:before { background-position: -2001.4% 0; }
<div class="imgWrap">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="imgWrap">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно, чтобы добавить префиксы поставщиков для поддержки браузера. Дополнительные сведения см. в разделе [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Split background image with 3D thickness effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39876163/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще одно решение, основанное на одном элементе.

Идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать несколько фоновых изображений для создания разных слоев над исходным изображением, чтобы:

- Создаать промежуток между каждой частью изображения, используя белый
  цвет (или тот же цвет, что и основной фон).
- Создать тень для каждой части.
- Создайте эффект толщины, используя прозрачный цвет.

Затем мы делаем поворот с перспективой, чтобы получить трехмерную иллюзию.

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  max-width:600px;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background:
  /* */
  linear-gradient(24deg,transparent 54%,#aaa 57%)          0px  100%/30px 16px border-box border-box,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 10px 100%/8px 3px,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    10px 0   /8px 3px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         10px 0   /8px 100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               0 0      /10px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)          130px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 140px 100%/8px  3px,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    140px 0   /8px  3px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         140px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               130px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)          260px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 270px 100%/8px  3px,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    270px 0   /8px  3px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         270px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               260px 0   /10px 100%,
  
  url(https://picsum.photos/400/200/?image=1015) 0 0/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете оптимизировать код, используя маску, чтобы иметь прозрачность:

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  max-width:600px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border-left:30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background:
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 65%,#aaa 67%)   0  100%/30px 16px border-box border-box,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  0 0   /8px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)   130px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  140px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                        130px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)   260px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  270px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                        260px 0   /10px 100%,
  
  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/400/200) center/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#fff 51%)  160px 100%/10px 16px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)  290px 100%/10px 16px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 0     50%/160px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 0 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 0 100%/160px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 170px 50%/120px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 140px 0/150px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 140px 100%/150px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 300px 50%/130px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 270px 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 270px 100%/160px 8px;
  mask:
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#fff 51%)  160px 100%/10px 16px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)  290px 100%/10px 16px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 0     50%/160px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 0 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 0 100%/160px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 170px 50%/120px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 140px 0/150px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 140px 100%/150px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 300px 50%/130px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 270px 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 270px 100%/160px 8px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Split background image with 3D thickness effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50317230/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>